# traces on matrices with enteries in quaternions

Tags: functional-analysis

I am wondering if there exists any quaternionic valued trace $T:M_{n}(\mathbb{H}) \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ on a quaternionic matrix?
Where the trace is a linear functional on a C*-algebra with the property T(AB)=T(BA). generally, quaternions are not commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try $\frac12\sum_{ij}(A_{ij}B_{ji}+B_{ji}A_{ij})$ to restore commutativity.

Comment: Thank you so much that is interesting.